# Regex - Skip one or more lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following `String` that I need to parse. I am looking for the `Board State` for each `Slot` number.

```
Some lines...
SLOT  2 (RP/LC 2): Random Text
   MAIN:
   PCA:
... More text
Board State is Val
... More text

Some lines...
SLOT  3 (RP/LC 3): Random Text
   MAIN:
   PCA:
... More text
Board State is Val2
... More text
subslot 0/9/0
```

Currently I have this.

```
String regex = "(^SLOT\\s*\\d+).*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*.*\\s*(Board.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(commandOutput);

while(matcher.find()) {
     //Do Something
}
```

I am hard coding the number of lines it needs to skip but I don't like this and it's bad programming.

Is it possible to do something like

```
regex = "(^SLOT\\s*\\d+)(.*\\s*)+(Board.*)"; //This obviously doesn't work. Find slot, then skip one or more lines until it finds Board. I am using \\s instead of \\r\\n because \\s skips tabs as well.
```

Edit: As to precisely what I want from the regex. Put `SLOT #` in a group and the `Board State is Val` in another group for all the `SLOTS`.

Comment: What text are you trying to capture and what text/line do you want to skip?

Comment: The `Board State` for each `SLOT` i.e. `SLOT 2 - Board State is Val`, `SLOT 3 - Board State is Val2` so on and so forth. There are multiple `SLOT`, I only put 2 here as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this simplified regex for your problem like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("SLOT\\s+(\\d+).*?Board\\s+State\\s+is\\s+(\\w+)",
            Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text);
while(m.find())
    System.out.printf("Slot is [%s], Board is [%s]%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Slot is [2], Board is [Val]
Slot is [3], Board is [Val2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
String regex = "(SLOT\\s*\\d+)\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)\\s*:\\s*\\S*[\n\r](\\s*[^\n\r]+[\n\r])*(Board[^\n\r]*)";
```

Notice that I have used `[^\n\r]` instead of `.` in case you compile it using `DOTALL`. If not, you can as easily change every `[^\n\r]` to `.`.

If the `(something): something` part is not mandatory after the `SLOT \d+` part, you can use thins one:

```
String regex = "(SLOT\\s*\\d+)[^\n\r]*[\n\r](\\s*[^\n\r]+[\n\r])*(Board[^\n\r]*)";
```

Comment: I am not using the `^` in front of the regex. I using it in front of the `group` as there are `subslots` in the text that I do not want. I only want the `SLOT` which is at the beginning of the line. You have an unclosed `[` and an unopened or extra `)`.

Comment: There is no match. I modified your answer to `regex = "(SLOT\\s*\\d+)\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)\\s*:\\s*\\S*([^\n\r]+[\n\r])*(Board)[^\n\r]*";`(added group () in slot and board) as I need to save it in a group and add it to a Map. It doesn't go inside `while(matcher.find())`. I will add the extra two lines in my question to show the code.

Comment: I have assumed that the `(something): something` part is mandatory for each SLOT. Was I incorrect?

Comment: Also, I had forgotten to add `[\n\r]` to detect the first line of each SLOTs declaration.

Comment: Which part? In `SLOT  2 (RP/LC 2): Random Text` I only want `SLOT 2` Then just the `Board State` which is `Val` for `SLOT 2`. As to precisely what i am looking for...Save `SLOT NUM` in one group and `Board Value` in another for all the `SLOTS`.

Comment: I believe this is the part where the problem is `([^\n\r]+[\n\r])*`. This output is coming from an IOS-XR device and it may or may not have tabs or other `empty` characters that we see as `space`. This `([^\n\r]+[\n\r])*` is basically `(.*\\s*)*`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I assumed none of the intermediary lines could start with a whitespace character. I was wrong. I edited the answer.